# Magento 1.13 Product URLs

Tags: magento-enterprise, url-rewrite

I have recently upgraded Magento  with the Latest Magento 1.13.1.0.
Now the issue is the URLS in older version are like

```
categroy1/subcategory1/test-product.html  
category2/test-product.html
brand/test-product.html
brand/new-product.html
```

where the product is assgin to 3 different categories. But after upgrade and when i run the url_migration_to_1.13.php all the urls are updated and the new url are weird.

Some of the urls are like

```
test-product-1.html
new-product-1-395db788289ee286662bbcabe78d99da.html
```

My client do not want to lose any previous URLs from older Magento.

Can any one suggest me any idea?

Thanks

Comment: did you ever manage to solve this issue?

Comment: Nope , still waiting for some solutions. I reach out to Magento for the solution and they said , we need to remove the duplicate urls ,

Comment: AFAIR the migration script creates rewrites from the old URLs to the new ones.

Answer (score 1):

In admin panel, **System->configuration->catalog(leftside)->catalog-> Search Engine Optimization** , There is a field named as: **Use Category Path for Product URL's**. Make this option as **"YES"**. Then it will display as previous with the category name also. Dont forget to **Re-Index** after making changes. Clear **CACHE** once your reindexing is successful..

Comment: Its already set to "Yes" and i already tried reindexing and cache is already disabled. WHen i look into some other product , i found its working for some of the product , but for some product its still showing the urls i mention in my post.
The one which are showing with proper category/subcategory url are still having structure like 

categroy1/subcategory1/test-product-1.html  
category2/test-product1-1-395db788289ee286662bbcabe78d99da.html

Comment: I found that there are some duplicate product urls and i am in progress to make it unique , but i want to know , do i also need to make it unique store wise , e.g for multi website , if the product url is abcd.html for one website do i need to change in my other website as well ?

Comment: no. It is not required to change. If you want to change the url in the another store, you can also change